# If I use compression with Avro does it make sense to enable Topic Compression in Kafka?

Tags: compression, apache-kafka, avro

In Kafka you can set properties on your Producer to compress keys and and values.

> `compression.codec` This parameter allows you to specify the compression codec for all data generated by this producer. Valid values are "none", "gzip" and "snappy".

http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs

When using the Confluent platform I can use the `KafkaAvroSerialization` serializer.  If I define `avro.codec` is there any point using Kafka's compression or vice versa?

> `avro.codec` the name of the compression codec used to compress blocks, as a string. Implementations are required to support the following codecs: "null" and "deflate". If codec is absent, it is assumed to be "null". The codecs are described with more detail below.

https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/spec.html#Object+Container+Files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While KafkaAvroSerializetion allows you to use Avro, you can't actually use avro.codec while doing so.

Why? Because avro.codec is used by Avro's DataFileWriter, which is not used in KafkaAvroSerialization (it uses DatumWriter directly to generate byte[] records rather than files).

So you will only ever get non-compressed records and **should set compression codec in the producer**. This also means the producer gets a chance to compress buffers containing more than one message and thereby improve the efficiency of the compression.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thank you.